# xmltodict.unparse is not handling CDATA properly

Tags: python, xmltodict

I am trying to use xmltodict to manipulate an XML content as python object, but I am facing an issue to handle properly CDATA. I think I am missing something somewhere, this is my code:

```
import xmltodict

data = """<node1>
    <node2 id='test'><![CDATA[test]]></node2>
    <node3 id='test'>test</node3>
</node1>"""

data = xmltodict.parse(data,force_cdata=True, encoding='utf-8')
print data

print xmltodict.unparse(data, pretty=True)
```

And this is the output:

```
OrderedDict([(u'node1', OrderedDict([(u'node2', OrderedDict([(u'@id', u'test'), ('#text', u'test')])), (u'node3', OrderedDict([(u'@id', u'test'), ('#text', u'test')]))]))])
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<node1>
        <node2 id="test">test</node2>
        <node3 id="test">test</node3>
</node1>
```

We can see here that the CDATA is missing in the generated node2, and also node2 is the same as node3. However, in the input the nodes are different.

Regards

Comment: Have you seen [the closed issue](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict/issues/57) on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working by performing this monkey-patch. I am still not very happy with it, It's really a 'hack' this feature should be included somewhere properly:

```
import xmltodict
def escape_hacked(data, entities={}):
    if data[0] == '<' and  data.strip()[-1] == '>':
        return '<![CDATA[%s]]>' % data

    return escape_orig(data, entities)


xml.sax.saxutils.escape = escape_hacked
```

and then run your python code normally:

```
data = """<node1>
    <node2 id='test'><![CDATA[test]]></node2>
    <node3 id='test'>test</node3>
</node1>"""

data = xmltodict.parse(data,force_cdata=True, encoding='utf-8')
print data

print xmltodict.unparse(data, pretty=True)
```

To explain, the following line detect if the data is a valid XML, then it add the CDATA tag arround it:

```
    if data[0] == '<' and  data.strip()[-1] == '>':
        return '<![CDATA[%s]]>' % data
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I want to clarify that there is no officially supported way to keep the `CDATA` section.

You could check [the issue](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict/issues/57) here.

Based on the above facts, you need DIY. There are two approaches:

Firstly, let's create some helper functions.

```py
def cdata(s):
    return '<![CDATA[' + s + ']]>'

def preprocessor(key, value):
    '''Unneccessary if you've manually wrapped the values. For example,

    xmltodict.unparse({
        'node1': {'node2': '<![CDATA[test]]>', 'node3': 'test'}
    })
    '''

    if key in KEEP_CDATA_SECTION:
        if isinstance(value, dict) and '#text' in value:
            value['#text'] = cdata(value['#text'])
        else:
            value = cdata(value)
    return key, value
```

1. Unescaping the escaped XML

```py
import xmltodict
from xml.sax.saxutils import unescape

KEEP_CDATA_SECTION = ['node2']

out_xml = xmltodict.unparse(data, preprocessor=preprocessor)
out_xml = unescape(out_xml) # not safe !
```

You shall not try it on the untrusted data, cuz this approach not only unescapes the character data but also unescapes the nodes' attributes.

2. Subclassing `XMLGenerator`

To alleviate the safety problem of `unescape()` , we could remove the `escape()` call in `XMLGenerator` so that there is no need to unescape the XML again.

```py
class XMLGenerator(xmltodict.XMLGenerator):
    def characters(self, content):
        if content:
            self._finish_pending_start_element()
            self._write(content) # also not safe, but better !

xmltodict.XMLGenerator = XMLGenerator
```

It is not a hack, so it won't change the rest behavior of `xmltodict` other than `unparse()` . More importantly, it won't pollute the built-in library `xml` .

For one-line fans.

```py
xmltodict.XMLGenerator.characters = xmltodict.XMLGenerator.ignorableWhitespace # now, it is a hack !
```

Even more, you can wrap the character data directly in `XMLGenerator` like the following.

```py
class XMLGenerator(xmltodict.XMLGenerator):
    def characters(self, content):
        if content:
            self._finish_pending_start_element()
            self._write(cdata(content))
```

From now on, every nodes having character data will keep the `CDATA` section.